# C++ decimal data types

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, double, decimal

Is there a way to use decimal data types such as `decimal32`, `decimal64` or `decimal128`in my C++ programs?

Comment: C++ doesn't have any decimal types built-in. You'll need a 3rd-party library.

Comment: Yeah I know that, do you know a library which can do that?

Comment: We are currently using this implementation which is working well  http://sourceforge.net/projects/stddecimal/

Comment: There is also the [Bloomberg bde](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/04a94fe1321b739eff5bc7dd221f89c6ab885304/groups/bdl/bdldfp/bdldfp_decimal.h) library which has [bdldfp_decimal.h](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/04a94fe1321b739eff5bc7dd221f89c6ab885304/groups/bdl/bdldfp/bdldfp_decimal.h) and [bdldfp_decimalutil.h](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/04a94fe1321b739eff5bc7dd221f89c6ab885304/groups/bdl/bdldfp/bdldfp_decimalutil.h).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The classes from the [Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) are not implemented for all compilers. Some compilers, e.g., [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org), implement the [C Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1312.pdf) and provide the corresponding extensions in C++, too. In the past there was an open source implementation for the C++ Decimal TR available but I failed to locate it. If your compiler doesn't support the decimal types, your best option is probably to create a wrapper for IBM's [decNumber library](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html).

To improve the situation in the future of C++, I have created a [plan to update the TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) and I'm going to turn the current TR into a complete proposal ready for the next C++ committee meeting (in April in Bristol), trying to get it adopted into the C++ standard, possibly into the revision planned for 2014. The implementation I have is part of my regular work and it isn't up to me to decide whether it is can be made available publically although there is some hope that it can be open sourced at some point.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie, so don't judge me if I don't understand well... I saw that gcc has this library to implement the Decimal TR: http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/ Do you know how can I use it in my programs?

Comment: @fpiro07, if you use the G++ compiler then libstdc++ (and its included implementation of the decimal extensions) are available automatically.

Comment: The decimals used by gcc are **not** in the library! There are certainly no decimal classes in libstdc++. The logic is built into the compiler. If you use gcc you can configure it when building gcc to include decimal support (by default it isn't included). If use clang or a gcc without decimal support enabled, you win't get decimal support from gcc or its libstdc++.

Comment: Dietmar, can you provide an update now that the April meeting has taken place?

Comment: @jwatt: For various reasons I didn't manage to get a paper ready for the Bristol meeting (aside from time also the fact that C started to work on the topic again and that it wouldn't make into C++2014 anyway). The updated plan is to update the TR and target C++2017...

Comment: @DietmarKühl: can you give us an update on your work?

Comment: @Bouncner: although it is still something I’m intersted in, there isn’t anything actively progressing. I had created http://wg21.link/n3407 which was discussed at the Chicago meeting in the Numerics SG. Since then nothing really happened.

Answer (score 19):

You can use easy to use header-only solution for C++ with templates:
https://github.com/vpiotr/decimal_for_cpp

Notice that this is not a **Big**Decimal class; it is limited to 64 bits' worth of "mantissa" digits.

[taken from link]

```
  #include "decimal.h"

  using namespace dec;

  // the following declares currency variable with 2 decimal points
  // initialized with integer value (can be also floating-point)
  decimal<2> value(143125);

  // to use non-decimal constants you need to convert them to decimal
  value = value / decimal_cast<2>(333.0);

  // output values
  cout << "Result is: " << value << endl;
  // this should display something like "429.80"

  // to mix decimals with different precision use decimal_cast
  decimal<6> exchangeRate(12.1234);
  value = decimal_cast<2>(decimal_cast<6>(value) * exchangeRate);

  cout << "Result 2 is: " << value << endl;
  // this should display something like "5210.64"

  cout << "Result 2<6> is: " << decimal_cast<6>(value) << endl;
  // this should display something like "5210.640000"
```

Comment: More constructor required, like ```dec::decimal<2> vol = 1.002;``` (clang 11.0) see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822438/in-copy-initialization-is-the-call-to-the-copy-constructor-explicit-or-implicit

Answer (score 4):

use an int32 or int64, and (manually) shift the decimal point to where you want it to be. If you're measuring dollars, for example, just measure cents instead and display the value differently. simple!

Comment: This approach works if you actually have one specific scale you need to support. If you need to deal with a wide variety of scales (government dept on the high end and foreign exchange or interest rates at the other end) even using `int64_t` doesn't give you enough digits for a  common scale. The simple solution works for simple uses but fails at least for some applications.

Comment: Please notice that 64 bits of mantissa, even if you use centicents, gives you a maximum of 9e15 for the largest integer number you can store. This is still a *huge* number (even for a government debt ;-)

Comment: This is called fixed point arithmetic and there are libraries like [CNL](https://github.com/johnmcfarlane/cnl) that offer you this in C++. IIRC there was the proposal [P0037R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0037r5.html) for standardization as well, but I'm not sure of its current status. In C this is introduced by the [Embeded C extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C) according to Wikipedia. Not a bad idea, if it suits the domain, but I think the question asks something different.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has cpp_dec_float as well. That's probably the best solution until it's adopted into the standard.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html

EDIT: This library uses floating point values in the implementation so is not a true decimal math library IMO.

Comment: got artifacts with this. after some time adding and removing small numbers (to:  typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<12> > decimal; type variable), started to get 5e-35.. instead of 0. not sure what I did wrong.  (but decimal_for_cpp worked.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Completely my fault for assuming the implementation. It is floating point types underneath. So used to decimal types in other areas to not use floating point values, I _assumed_ this was the same. Live and learn.

Answer (score -4):

decimal.h this library is not exit is is saying by my compiler.

````
/tmp/TQDyfEvEXQ.cpp:2:10: fatal error: decimal.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <decimal.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sure, sir, I will follow.