# In which segment a given floating point number lies in?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose to have `n` (integer) contiguous segments of length `l` (floating point). That is:

```
Segment 0 = [0, l)
Segment 1 = [l, 2*l)
Segment 2 = [2*l, 3*l)
... 
Segment (n-1) = [(n-1)*l, n*l)
```

Given a number `x` (floating point), I want to write a function

```
int getSegmentId(double x, double l, int n)
```

which returns the id of the segment where `x` lies.

I would like to do this in O(1), not O(log(n)) by checking if `x` lies in each interval.

I think this is a very general and common problem and I guess there is one solution for this. Have you any hint for me?

**Addendum**

The question is not about a particular implementation of this algorithm like in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096660/in-which-segment-a-given-number-lies-in) based on floating point operations. I'm just asking which is <s>the best</s> **a good and robust way** to implement this.

Comment: Would `lround()`'ing the double before adding it to the int do what you want?

Comment: *"I'm just asking which is the **best way** to implement this"* that's too opinionated for this site.

Comment: @KevinB changed "best way" to "good and robust way". Is it better?

Comment: Not really. I'm not sure how you could salvage this.

Comment: @KevinB I don't understand what's wrong with my question...

Comment: If the only thing that makes your question different from the duplicate is you want the best, or a good, way of doing it, I don't think that's enough of a difference to make it not a dupe. What makes your question different, that's what you need to explain within your question.

Comment: @KevinB ok, but my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096660/in-which-segment-a-given-number-lies-in) was marked as duplicate because I was asking how to solve the problem using floating point math. Now, I'm asking how to solve the problem, not necessarily using floating point math.

Comment: you already have *an* answer to that, explain why you are looking for more ways to do it or why that way won't work for you.

Comment: @KevinB I'm looking for more ways because if I use something like (int)floor(x / l), I can sometimes obtain ambiguous results as remarked in my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096660/in-which-segment-a-given-number-lies-in).

Comment: If 'l' would be a decimal (with decimal places) and `n*l` a decimal, then it becomes a different question. However your query is `int getSegmentId(double x, double l, int n)` and not `int getSegmentId(double x, decimal l, int n)`

Comment: @DieterLücking it seems it has become a philosophical problem about number representations... It sounds strange to me that this kind of problem has never been tackled and solved. I give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int getSegmentId(double x, double l, double n)
{
    if(x>=n*l){
        //cout>> "Not in any segments! ";
        return -1;
    else
        return (int) x/l ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem, if each segment starts at `i*l` and ends at `(i+1)*l` then

```
int s = static_cast<int>(std::floor(x / l));
```

should be enough.

Comment: is it enough? Don't think it always works. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096660/in-which-segment-a-given-number-lies-in) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)