# Is there a better way to store more digits after the decimal point, than long double?

Tags: c++, variables, double, long-integer, pi

I am currently working on a problem that calculates pi. The calculating part works fine but with my current data-type I can only calculate a certain amount of digits, before it stops storing them (~32?).

I am using a long double, but I want more digits, preferably a variable amount.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
//variables
float sign = 1.0;
long double sum = 0.0;
float start = 3.0;
int iteration = 0.0;

int main() {

    std::cout << "How many iterations should be completed?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> iteration;
//calculating part
    for (int j = 1; j < iteration; j++) {
        sum = sum + sign * 4.0 / ((2 * j) * (2 * j + 1.0) * (2 * j + 2.0));
        sign *= -1.0;
    }
//output     
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1000) << sum + start << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get what I expect, but I did not find a data-type, that stores even more. Do I have to write one myself?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319967/exact-decimal-datatype-for-c

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll have a look into that tomorrow.