# In copy-initialization, is the call to the copy constructor explicit or implicit?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer

```
class AAA {
public:
    explicit AAA(const AAA&) {}
    AAA(int) {}
};


int main() {
    AAA a = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, as I understand, though elided in most cases, the copy constructor is still semantically required to be called.  My question is, is the call explicit or implicit?  For a long time I have the conclusion in my mind that the call to `AAA::AAA(int)` is implicit but the call to the copy constructor is not.  Today I accidentally got g++ to compile the above code and it reported error.  (VC12 compiles OK.)

In section 8.5 of the standard:

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
>     type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
>     destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors
>     are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload
>     resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize
>     the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its
>     argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is
>     ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source
>     type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used)
>     to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4,
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the
>     conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is
>     ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer
>     expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call
>     initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified version of the
>     destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call
>     (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to
>     **direct-initialize**, according to the rules above, the object that is
>     the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, an
>     implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this
>     direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly
>     into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

The bolded `direct-initialize` in the above quotes means the call to copy constructor is explicit, right?  Is g++ wrong or my interpretation of the standard wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this bug: [g++ fails to call explicit constructors in the second step of copy initialization](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54521)

> g++ fails to compile the following code
>
> ```
> struct X
> {
>     X(int) {}
>     explicit X(X const &) {}
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>     X x = 1; // error: no matching function for call to 'X::X(X)'
> }
> ```
>
> The second step of a copy initialization (see 8.5/16/6/2) is a
>   direct-initialization where explicit constructors shall be considered
>   as candidate functions.

Comment: This is not a bug: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit "Specifies constructors and (since C++11) conversion operators that don't allow implicit conversions or copy-initialization. " marking the constructor explicit disable copy-initialization. You must do X x(1);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like copy constructor is never called . Only constructor is called . The following code may call copy constructor

```
AAA a = 1;
AAA ab = a;
```

Not sure why G++ is compiling it .