# Explicit keyword, move constructor and copy constructor, and disabling move and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, move, explicit

I understand what explicit keyword does to a constructor with a single parameter, it can surely limit the possibility of unwanted behaviour. I also understand what move and copy constructors do.

What I don't understand is, how explicit constructor affects move and copy constructors, and I have also seen a case when you can disable copy and move constructors... Why would you do all that? All that is very vague to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529772/explicit-copy-constructor-and-stdsort?rq=1 ?

Comment: You'd disable copying because it may not be logical to copy objects of a class. Singleton's shouldn't be copyable, for instance.

Comment: I am asking about explicit copy constructor, but about explicit constructor, and how it affects copy and move constructors. That does not answer my question, but thanks, I will read that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit copy constructor works the same way as an explicit converting constructor - it cannot be invoked implicitly. The only difference is what your object is constructed from.

I would also believe that the uses cases for this are extremely rare and far between.

Slightly more common case is to have the class' copy constructor and assignment operator deleted (`= delete`). This is useful for objects that represent a unique resource, and therefore should not be copied. `std::cout` is an example of an object that exists, but should not be copied.