# C++ Write a long float number to a file

Tags: c++

file.txt

```
123.56
89.78
8.89
468.98
567.90
5.78
178908.90
12.56
6789.90
12.56
16.780
0.00
```

I've parsed the numbers into an array called float A[150] = {0}.
So, A looks like:

```
A[0] = 123.56
A[1] = 89.78
....
....
A[10] = 16.780
A[11] = 0.00
A[12] = 0
A[13] = 0
...
...
```

Then, I have a sorting Algorithm

```
Sort(A, i) // where i is the number of elements (12)
```

Now A[] looks like

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 5.78
...
...
A[10] = 6789.90
A[11] = 178908.90
```

Then, I write it to a file called "Final.txt"

```
std::ofstream File (Name);
if (File.is_open())
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            File << A[j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

The file output "Final.txt" looks like:

```
0
5.78
8.89
12.56
12.56
16.78
89.78
123.56
468.98
567.9
6789.9
178909 // Why it is NOT CORRECT !!!!!!!
```

The problem with A[11] after the sorting, why is it not correct in "Final.txt", even though it is correct when I debug it in the A[11] ?

Comment: That's far from what I'd consider a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also don't you have a frickin' debugger?

Comment: Have a look at [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) et al.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point values are printed with several constraints to make the values readable. For instance you would probably not want the output of 
16.78 to read

```
16.799999999999998
```

Which might well be a more correct representation of `16.78`. To avoid that `operator <<` operation on ostreams uses a precision field to determine how many significant digits to print.  This value is obviously set too small for your application.

Reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision.

Other formatting settings is given by the link πάντα ῥεῖ provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have different problems when trying to output 178908.90

First, the default implementation of c++ ostream normally outputs `178909`, because as explained by Captain Giraffe, the default format does its best to avoid irrelevant digits and precision

You could try to force a fixed floating point with 2 digits in precision but then you will get 178908.91 (if you use float and not double). Because you would fall in second problem : in C++, floating point numbers (float or double) use [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) format which offers only about 7 decimal digits in precision, and internally it is more like : `178908.906`

So the rule is : if you want to keep roughly the input precision, do not use numbers of more than 6 decimal digits for float and 14 for double, and if you want to keep strictly input precision, do not use floating point at all !

You can try to use decimal types as shown in that other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096071/3545273), or build your own class.