# C++17 And the Current State of Decimal Floating Point

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, c++17

What is the current status of decimal floating point in C++?  I am specifically looking for the status of language inclusion, standards compliance and portability.

There are a host of "official" libraries floating around which are based on existing standards (notably IEEE754-2008) which have been heralded as the groundwork for standards inclusion:

- [Bloomberg BDL Decimal Float Library](https://bloomberg.github.io/bde/group__bdldfp__decimal.html)
- [libdfp (originally IBM Decimal Floating Point Library)](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp)

Additionally, there was a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html) to add decimal floats to C++14. According to the proposer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096026/c-decimal-data-types) it was not submitted in time for inclusion (see comments on answer).

I have also checked numerous sources for [C++17 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17), but I cannot find mention of Decimal Floating Point.

I know that some compilers (such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html) and Clang) have implemented their own extensions based on what they *believe* the spec will look like.  However, these extensions obviously cannot offer full support / portability for a spec that has not been officially ratified yet (as far as I am aware).

Where are we in August of 2017 on official decimal floating point support?

Comment: is this even on topic?  If it isn't I'm not even sure what exchange site this would go under.

Comment: @snb Certainly not at any meta-site. And I think the question is _on-topic_.

Comment: @snb It's relevant to programming and feasibly answerable, so I'd say it's on topic.

Comment: According to [this](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-proposal-status.html) there is no status for N3407

Comment: As far as I can tell, that document was last updated in 2013.  Has there really been no progress since then?

Comment: @phobos51594 Oh, didn't see that.  You can get a more current list [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/#Post-C++11).  That said I did find [this](https://wongmichael.com/category/c/) that says more than likely it will be a no.  I'm trying to find something more concrete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C[++17 is feature-complete](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/15/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-toronto/) at this point, and going out for the final vote. So [whatever is there right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17?noredirect=1&lq=1) is what's going to be in it when the final ISO vote is made, modulo bugs/defects of course.

Decimal floats were not voted in, so they're not going to be in C++17. The last paper on the subject, [N3871](http://wg21.link/N3871), was written in 2014. So it seems clear that nobody's really trying to move it forward.

Comment: They are probably waiting for the final iterations of the C Decimal TS, for which there has been extensive work. Some parts of it (the ones that may be adaopted in C++) target the next C standard revision, C2x.

Comment: @Morwenn: actually, I'm not really waiting for anything although I will probably have a look at the C Decimal TS if I get to work on a proposal for inclusion into C++. Essentially, I don't manage to work on the proposal.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'm almost disappointed it's not actually a subtle plan to incorporate all the work of the C TS to get decimal floating point numbers in the standard with flying colors D: