# What is an alternative to int, I need to have decimals

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++, and I need type values which aren't int for decimals. Anyone have some?

I have tried `dec` and `decimal` but they don't work.

this is my code right now:

```
dec Number = 31;
```

Thanks for having a look at my question!

Comment: How about `double`?

Comment: @Beta Never for money. When you need precision, never use floating point. If you don't have access to a proper decimal type, use an integer nevertheless; e.g. to represent $6.32 dollars, use 632 cents instead.

Comment: Are you talking about real numbers vs integral numbers?

Comment: @Amadan: Who said anything about money?

Comment: @Beta: I did. Because there are times when `float` or `double` is great, and there's times when it's a felony (and everything in between). Adding a warning to "how about `double`" is just common sense.

Comment: @Amadan: That's absurd. No data type is good for all applications, and adding warnings to *every possible suggestion* is just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Beta: Given that OP is asking for "decimal", which names a data type specifically designed to represent fixed-point real number, and almost exclusively used to avoid problems with floating point arithmetics, and was likely trying to use [C++ extensions that implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096026/c-decimal-data-types)... I'd say the warning is very relevant.

Comment: "Decimal" doesn't necessarily imply that the OP knows that "decimal" is a type. It could just mean he wants digits after a '.'. A floating point type is the obvious first answer. Either way, both answers are making some assumptions. Original poster, please be a bit more detailed in your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `double` or `float`

Hope this helps!