# changing decimals to integars

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to convert decimals into whole integers.
Thus, far I have found three methods that kind of work and several that don't.
It seems mighty peculiar that:

A: Trials A and B fail at the opposite ends of the spectrum.

B: If I change the values `0.14` and `0.28` inside of the array `arr_decimals[7]` then trial C works. Any value with a `4` or an `8` at those two indices fail! Just about any other value works.

Literally, just changed `14` to `17` and `28` to `27`.

I have been struggling with these three solutions for four days and none of them work, completely.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // long doubles for scalablility
    long double arr_decimals[7]{ 0.02, 0.06, 0.1, 0.14, 0.18, 0.22, 0.28 };

    long double arr_pre_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    long double arr_not_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    long double arr_input_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    long double arr_test_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int var_array_length = 7;
    int var_int_value = 0;
    bool bool_more_trailing_zeros = 0;

    // trial A:
    std::cout << "trial A:" << std::endl;
    for (int var_change = 0; var_change < var_array_length; var_change++)
    {
        if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.000001 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.000009)        arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10000000;       // seven decimals places
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.00001 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.00009)     arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 1000000;        // six ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.0001 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.0009)       arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 100000;         // five ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.001 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.009)         arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10000;          // four ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.01 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.09)           arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 1000;           // three ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] >= 0.1 && arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.9)             arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 100;            // two ..
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 1)                                                  arr_pre_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10;             // one ..
        else                                                                                    std::cout << "Error: unexpected value: " << arr_decimals[var_change] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "arr_pre_values: " << arr_pre_values[var_change] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // trial B:
    std::cout << "trial B:" << std::endl;
    for (int var_change = 0; var_change < var_array_length; var_change++)
    {
        if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.000001)        arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10000000;       // seven decimals places
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.000009)   arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 1000000;        // six ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.00009)    arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 100000;         // five ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.0009)     arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10000;          // four ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.009)      arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 1000;           // three ...
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 0.09)       arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 100;            // two ..
        else if (arr_decimals[var_change] < 1)          arr_not_values[var_change] = arr_decimals[var_change] * 10;             // one ..
        else                                            std::cout << "Error: unexpected value: " << arr_decimals[var_change] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "arr_not_values: " << arr_not_values[var_change] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // trial C:
    std::cout << "trial C:" << std::endl;
    std::copy(std::begin(arr_decimals), std::end(arr_decimals), std::begin(arr_input_values));
    for (int var_change = 0; var_change < var_array_length; var_change++)
    {
        bool_more_trailing_zeros = 1;
        while (bool_more_trailing_zeros)
        {
            std::cout << "arr_input_values: " << arr_input_values[var_change] << std::endl;
            var_int_value = static_cast<long double>(arr_input_values[var_change]);
            std::cout << "var_int_value: " << var_int_value << std::endl;

            // compare long double to int
            if (arr_input_values[var_change] != var_int_value)
            {
                arr_input_values[var_change] *= 10;
            }
            // move value and end loop
            else // if (arr_input_values[var_change] == var_int_value)
            {
                arr_test_values[var_change] = arr_input_values[var_change];
                bool_more_trailing_zeros = 0;
            }
        }
        std::cout << typeid(var_int_value).name() << " --------->> " << "arr_test_values: " << arr_test_values[var_change] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

failed console print out:

```
>! arr_pre_values: 20
>! arr_pre_values: 60
>! arr_pre_values: 10
>! arr_pre_values: 14
>! arr_pre_values: 18
>! arr_pre_values: 22
>! arr_pre_values: 28
>! 
>! arr_not_values: 2
>! arr_not_values: 6
>! arr_not_values: 1
>! arr_not_values: 1.4
>! arr_not_values: 1.8
>! arr_not_values: 2.2
>! arr_not_values: 2.8
>! 
>! arr_input_values: 0.02
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 0.2
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 2
>! var_int_value: 2
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 2
>! arr_input_values: 0.06
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 0.6
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 6
>! var_int_value: 6
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 6
>! arr_input_values: 0.1
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 1
>! var_int_value: 1
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 1
>! arr_input_values: 0.14
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 1.4
>! var_int_value: 1
>! arr_input_values: 14
>! var_int_value: 14
>! arr_input_values: 140
>! var_int_value: 140
>! arr_input_values: 1400
>! var_int_value: 1400
>! arr_input_values: 14000
>! var_int_value: 14000
>! arr_input_values: 140000
>! var_int_value: 140000
>! arr_input_values: 1.4e+06
>! var_int_value: 1400000
>! arr_input_values: 1.4e+07
>! var_int_value: 14000000
>! arr_input_values: 1.4e+08
>! var_int_value: 140000000
>! arr_input_values: 1.4e+09
>! var_int_value: 1400000000
>! to INF and beyond!
```

successuful console print out for trial C:

```
>! arr_input_values: 0.02
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 0.2
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 2
>! var_int_value: 2
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 2
>! arr_input_values: 0.06
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 0.6
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 6
>! var_int_value: 6
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 6
>! arr_input_values: 0.1
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 1
>! var_int_value: 1
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 1
>! arr_input_values: 0.17
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 1.7
>! var_int_value: 1
>! arr_input_values: 17
>! var_int_value: 17
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 17
>! arr_input_values: 0.18
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 1.8
>! var_int_value: 1
>! arr_input_values: 18
>! var_int_value: 18
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 18
>! arr_input_values: 0.22
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 2.2
>! var_int_value: 2
>! arr_input_values: 22
>! var_int_value: 22
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 22
>! arr_input_values: 0.27
>! var_int_value: 0
>! arr_input_values: 2.7
>! var_int_value: 2
>! arr_input_values: 27
>! var_int_value: 27
>! int --------->> arr_test_values: 27
```

Comment: I didn't look into the code. However when it comes to decimal, better not using `double` representing decimal values. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14096026/4123703) for more details.

Comment: Thanx Louis! I know 'float' is the preferred method here, but I wanna be able to use longer values later on.

Comment: Obligatory: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Neither `float` or `double` is proper... decimal is decimal and unfortunately C++ doesn't support it in standard. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) for details..

Answer (score 0):

Decimals are inaccurate. If you're just doing simple addition and subtraction and need exact numbers, you can use arrays to store decimals and integers separately.

Comment: thanxthat is the following ararys are for 'long double arr_input_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };' AND 'long double arr_test_values[7]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };'

Comment: Note: when the decimal is split, it should be two integers.